# bitcoin-cli not stopping bitcoind

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-cli, datadir

I tried stopping bitcoind using bitcoin-cli stop and got the following error.

```
bitcoin-cli stop
error: Could not locate RPC credentials. No authentication cookie could be found, and RPC password is not set.  See -rpcpassword and -stdinrpcpass.  Configuration file: (/home/user/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf)
```

I confirmed that bitcoind is running (using ps -A).

```
ps -A | grep bitcoind
643 pts/0    00:17:23 bitcoind
```

bitcoind was started in a datadir on the usb storage. I can kill the process but i want to shut it down in a correct way.

Comment: Try pointing `bitcoin-cli` to the same datadir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Raghav Sood mentioned, you can stop bitcoin for a different datadir (the location of `.bitcoin` folder) using:

`$ bitcoin-cli -datadir=<dir> stop`